# (Java) Значение, проверяемое if, истинно, но срабатывает else

Tags: java, if

Недавно начал учить Java, изучал if, решил вот такое написать. При вводе правильного username и password, которые соответствуют adminUsername и adminPassword, всё-равно срабатывает else.

```
`package cynder;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lyngot {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lyngotToWithdraw, lyngotBalance = 4923;
    double USD_toWithdraw, USD_Balance = 342;
    String username, password, adminPassword, adminUsername;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    adminUsername = "Michael";
    adminPassword = "Alexstrasza25";
    System.out.println("Welcome. Enter your username:");
    username = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your password");
    password = scan.nextLine();
    if(username == adminUsername && password == adminPassword) {
        System.out.println("Welcome. Write how much USD you want to withdraw:");
        USD_toWithdraw = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Write how much Lyngot you want to withdraw");
        lyngotToWithdraw = scan.nextInt();
        if(USD_toWithdraw >= USD_Balance) {
            if(lyngotToWithdraw >= lyngotBalance) {
                System.out.println("Please wait...");
                System.out.println("The operation was successful.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error. Not enough Lyngot on balance");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error. Not enough USD on balance");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong password or username");
    }
}
```

}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мало что понятно. Поясните, какой из `if` у вас "не работает".

Comment: Самый первый
 if(username == adminUsername && password == adminPassword)
Значения равны, а срабатывает else

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос, уберите лишний код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант , проблема была в том, что == сравнивает две ссылки на объекты, и если обе ссылки ссылаются на один и тот же объект(экземпляр), возвращаеся true,если нет - false. s1.equals(s2); сравнивает значение внутри экземпляров

```
if(username.equals(adminUsername) && password.equals(adminPassword))
```

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class qew {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lyngotToWithdraw, lyngotBalance = 4923;
    double USD_toWithdraw, USD_Balance = 342;
    String username, password, adminPassword, adminUsername;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    adminUsername = "Michael";
    adminPassword = "Alexstrasza25";
    System.out.println("Welcome. Enter your username:");
    username = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your password");
    password = scan.nextLine();
    if(username.equals(adminUsername) && password.equals(adminPassword)) {
        System.out.println("Welcome. Write how much USD you want to withdraw:");
        USD_toWithdraw = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Write how much Lyngot you want to withdraw");
        lyngotToWithdraw = scan.nextInt();
        if(USD_toWithdraw >= USD_Balance) {
            if(lyngotToWithdraw >= lyngotBalance) {
                System.out.println("Please wait...");
                System.out.println("The operation was successful.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error. Not enough Lyngot on balance");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error. Not enough USD on balance");
        }
    } else    System.out.println("Wrong password or username");
    
}
}
```